# Содержит ли socket.IO внутри цикл при отправки нескольким пользователям?

Tags: node.js, сокет, websocket, производительность, socket.io

Есть веб-приложение для управление фирмой. В этом приложении можно увидеть различные отчеты и статистики. Для обновлений данных в режиме реального времени я использовал `WebSocket` + `MysqlEvent`( `BackEnd` написан `PHP`).

Для того, чтобы обновлять данные другим участникам, я использую цикл, который перебирает всех подключенных пользователей и отсылает им данные в цикле.

В то время как `socket.IO` это сделано из коробки и без циклов.

Вопрос: `socket.IO` - использует внутренний цикл и отправляет данные приблизительно по такому принципу? Либо там другой способ, менее затратный? В наличии мощный сервер, но у Всего есть пределы.

Спасибо за любую информацию!

Comment: Скорее всего да, содержит

Comment: @KoVadim, оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог его выбрать как лучший?

Comment: я думаю, что после этого набегут сотни комментаторов с предложением, что это не является ответом и тому подобное.